# Nx Monorepo - NestJs Docker development reloading not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nestjs, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I want to run a Nx workspace containing a NestJs project in a Docker container, in development mode. The problem is I am unable to configure docker-compose + Dockerfile to make the project reload on save. I'm a bit confused on why this is not working as I configured a small nestjs project(without nx) in docker and it had no issues reloading on save.
Surely I am not mapping the ports corectly or something.

```
version: "3.4"

services:
    nx-app:
      container_name: nx-app
      build: .
      ports:
        - 3333:3333
        - 9229:9229
      volumes:
        - .:/workspace
```

```
FROM node:14.17.3-alpine

WORKDIR /workspace

COPY . .

RUN ["npm", "i", "-g", "@nrwl/cli"]
RUN ["npm", "i"]

EXPOSE 3333
EXPOSE 9229

ENTRYPOINT ["nx","serve","main"]
```

Also tried adding a Angular application to the workspace and was able to reload it on save in the container without issues...

Comment: Just resolved my problem by turning on this setting from docker: "Use gRPC FUSE for file sharing"

Comment: Where did you find that setting? Is it mac only? Because i'm using Docker Windows and i cant find something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve it by adding `"poll": 500` in project.json of nestJs app/library.

```
  "targets": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/node:webpack",
      ...
      "options": {
        ...
        "poll": 500
```